# How can I use multiple angularjs's controller inside a view (or subview of a multi-views)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-ui-router, angularjs-view

As title, I'd like to use more than one controller inside some sub-view

routes.js (eg.):

```
.state("multi",{
            url: "/multi",
            views: {
                "": {
                    templateUrl: "multipleView.htm",
                    controller: "MainCTRL",
                    controllerAs: "ctrl"
                },
                "viewA@multi": {
                    templateUrl: "testingBlock.htm",
                    controller: ["CtrlOne", "CtrlTwo"],
                    controllerAs: "ctrl"
                },
            });
```

Or should I put CtrlOne and CtrlTwo inside a third controller:

```
function CtrlThree($scope){
         CtrlOne($scope);
         CtrlOTwo($scope);
}
```

Comment: A couple things.  Firstly, naming every `controllerAs` the same is a recipe for disaster.  Secondly, your premise here seems flawed.  A controller's *only* purpose is to be the glue for a view, so having more than one controller for one view seems wrong.  What is it you are really trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not put the controller in the view instead of specifying it on the routeProvider.

Also do the controllers have a hierarchy or do you want them to all just work on the same level.

Example of what I mentioned above.

`<div ng-controller="CtrlOne">
    <div ng-controller="CtrlTwo"></div>
</div>`

This would be the html inside the "multipleView.htm" file.